Angular 17 SSR, Interceptor
Developing Angular 17 SSR applications, JWT Authentication
I developed login component, and trying to get the user info from JWT.
But, I'm not able to work with Interceptor & localStorage

Inteceptor [For showing loading information during Http calls & Auth bearer token`]
localStorage [For reading token from localstorage]
Unfortunately, I'm facing error localstorage undefined  & interceptors are not getting invoked

Code for Interceptor
export const KleverInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {

  // let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  // console.log("Interceptor token",token);
  // const authReq = req.clone({headers : req.headers.set('Authorization',`Bearer 
  //   ${token}`)})
  console.log("interceptor");

  return next(req);
};


 For understanding commented the code which Im trying to implement for httprequest 
Registering app.config.ts
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = { 
providers: [ 
provideRouter(routes),
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideHttpClient(withFetch(), withInterceptors([NeosparkInterceptor])),
]
}

With above, im not able to invoke interceptor properly.

When using SSR, your auth will need to be stored in a cookie.

Localstorage does not support for the Server side rendering, it is a Client side feature.
So you can use isPlatformBrowser function to check if you are running in the browser:
import { PLATFORM_ID, Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenService {
  private isBrowser: boolean;

  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
    this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);
  }

  getToken(): string | null {
    if (this.isBrowser) {
      return localStorage.getItem("token");
    }
    return null;
  }
}

Use this TokenService in the interceptor
